# Mismatch versions when using QUnit with JSTestDriver adapter (QUnitAdapter.js)

Tags: qunit, js-test-driver

I'm trying to run unit tests written in QUnit using jsTestDriver.
I'm getting "ReferenceError: equal is not defined".
Checking the source code shows that the adapter (Qunit->jsTestDriver) QUnitAdapter.js supports the equals method:

> [window.equals = function(a, b, msg) {...}](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/source/search?q=QUnitAdapter%20equals&origq=QUnitAdapter%20equals&btnG=Search%20Trunk)

While Qunit does not support equals ([renamed to equal last year](http://docs.jquery.com/index.php?title=QUnit&diff=21001&oldid=20777)).

Am I missing something here?

p.s. I'm using jsTestDriver which is integrated into WebStorm 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are using the QUnitAdapter from the JsTestDriver website. Currently, the adapter on that site only supports a small subset of what QUnit is capable of, so you should use the far more up-to-date and mature QUnitAdapter found [here](https://github.com/exnor/QUnit-to-JsTestDriver-adapter). I wrote a post that shows how to integrate QUnit, Requirejs, and code coverage with JSTD: [js-test-driver+qunit+coverage+requirejs](http://pseudobry.com/js-test-driver-qunit-coverage-requirejs/). Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep. [They say](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11464) it will be fixed in WebStorm 5.0.